# What does it mean by "Un coup de rouge" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the subtitle for the subsequent paragraphs in the article. It means "a glass of red wine" in French, but I cannot understand why the author chose this subtitle. Is it related to the left represented by Mr Mélenchon?

**Un coup de rouge**
Whoever is president will inherit a discontented country. Unemployment has been stuck above 10% since 2012; for young people, it is still above 20%. The economy is growing slowly and does not yield enough tax to pay for the public services that voters believe are their right. Racial and religious tensions run high, exacerbated by jihadist attacks. Dislike of the EU is even stronger than it was in pre-referendum Britain.

*The Economist, Apirl 22, The French election*
http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21721143-french-go-polls-they-are-angry-and-divided-consequential-choice-franceand

Comment: Probably need someone fluent in French here, but I believe it can also mean "a touch of red", and so might be commenting on the economic situation, or possibly as you speculate, the leftist leanings of Mélenchon. Whatever it is, not quite sure if it is our cup of tea on EL&U.

Comment: *coupe* can mean cup, but not *coup*...

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, this is a pun based on the po­lit­i­cal mean­ing of
the word *coup* and the as­so­ci­a­tion be­tween the the color red
and left-lean­ing Euro­pean pol­i­tics like those of com­mu­nism
and so­cial­ism.

Orig­i­nat­ing from the French ex­pres­sion *coup d’é­tat*,
which can [per Dic­tionary.com be de­fined as](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/coup-d-etat)

> **a sud­den and de­ci­sive ac­tion in pol­i­tics**, es­pe­cially
> one re­sult­ing in a change of gov­ern­ment il­le­gally or by force.

Wiki­pedia ob­serves that in pol­i­tics, the color red [is of­ten
as­so­ci­ated with the far-left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_colour#Red) — ex­cept in the United States
this mil­len­nium, where it has come to be as­so­ci­ated with the
far-right in­stead.

So the author made a sub­tle joke, us­ing two po­lit­i­cal words
to­gether to form a pun.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the pun may be that in the United States, the color red is associated with politics of the right, and *[**cou**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cou#French) de rouge* (without the *-p* but pronounced the same way *coup* is) can also be translated as “red neck.” Rednecks tend to vote for right-wing political candidates.

Comment: Your idea of them punning red-neck goes well with a right-wing take-over.